# How to get video/audio conversation time call / history quickblox?

Tags: php, quickblox

I am using [Quickblox-PHP-API](https://github.com/sonusindhu/Quickblox-PHP-API/blob/master/quickblox.php) but I want to get video/audio conversation time call / history in this API. Please let me know how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Officially, we don't provide PHP API.

It might help if you contact PHP-API branch contributors: https://github.com/sonusindhu/Quickblox-PHP-API/graphs/contributors to find out how to implement a conversation time call/history.

We plan to add native support of calls statistics in future.